# shorthand $q resolving / differing syntax

Tags: angularjs, promise

As i was watching this [tutorial video](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-chained-promises), i noticed the following in `FlightServices.js`:

```
return {
  getDeparture : function( user )
  {
    var dfd = $q.defer();

        // Mock departure information for the user's flight

        dfd.resolve({
            userID   : user.email,
            flightID : "UA_343223",
            date     : "01/14/2014 8:00 AM"
        });

    return dfd.promise;

  },
  getFlight : function( flightID )
  {
    return $q.resolve ({
        id    : flightID,
        pilot : "Captain Morgan",
        plane : {
            make  : "Boeing 747 RC",
            model : "TA-889"
        },
        status: "onTime"
    });
  }
};
```

As you can see, an instance of `$q.defer()` is used as the return value on `getDeparture()`, differing from `getFlight`, where $q.resolve() is directly returned.

Are there any (dis-)advantages in the latter? Or is this just a shorthand notation?
I have never seen this and would have thought that i need an instance of `defer()` in any case.

Answer (score 1):

The second syntax actually isn't valid syntax with vanilla AngularJS.

The author used a concept called decorators to add this functionality to the $q service:

https://github.com/ThomasBurleson/angularjs-FlightDashboard/blob/master/lib/%24QDecorator.js

If you're not familiar with decorators, there's a good video that explains them on egghead.io:

https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-provide-decorator